# Find element in appium

Tags: android, xpath, appium

How do I find an element in a linear layout which have a specific index, as obtain in the image I have this element [android.widget.EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgZwe.png), which has index 3. When I try to find it using the search parameter:
 
`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']")).SendKeys("123");` 
and  I tried this as well 
`driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText' and @index='3']").SendKeys("123");`

I get this exception 
`{"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters."}`

How can i select this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since index is involved , i would suggest u to put the element identifier in a list and and get index and click. Try the below code

```
List<WebElement> list= driver.findElements(By.XPath("identifier"));
System.out.println("size of List= " + list.size());
        list.get(3).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='3']")).SendKeys("123");` which is the syntax for searching for an xpath by attribute where @attribute is the attribute. For index, however, it is simpler. Just do `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.EditText[3]")).SendKeys("123");`

Comment: you could be looking for the element before the page is finished loading. try using a wait first (http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: No change and when try to search using id find the same problem `driver.FindElement(By.Id("password_edit_text")).SendKeys("123456");`

Comment: have you tried using appium inspector to verify your locator queries are correct? You have to be absolutely sure your queries are correct AND that the page is loaded before the search is executed.